# RewriteRule pass along query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to make a system, so when you visit the link
about.php
it will make it seem like you go through index.php?page=about

I did this using htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

My problem is that if i access fx about.php?avar=set this does not pass through.
I simply dont know much about htaccess files or how to set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule add `QSA` and `L` flags:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.php$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.